Require a nested object to have a property using TypeScript
I want to enforce the following.
interface Foo {
    propName: string;
 
    nested: {
        // The nested object must contain a property that matches propName
        // eg, if propName: 'foo', then nested: { foo: '' }
    }
}

Something like this
interface Foo2<TName extends string=string> {
    propName: TName;
 
    nested: {
        [key in TName] : unknown
    }
}
 
const foo: Foo2 = {
    propName: 'bar',
    nested: {
        fail: 1 // Should fail because does not have a 'bar' property
    }
}

I see that the problem is in getting TypeScript to see 'bar' as a string literal.
I'm not sure that this is possible?

This is an advanced TS question so would the noobs stop down-voting it? As I said, I’m not sure TypeScript supports this functionality — although it is a compelling use case.

why is the generic type TName optional? why wont you want to pass the type into Foo2?

There's no specific type in TS that works this way. You can make a generic type, as you've done, but then you either need to specify the type argument explicitly (as the answer below shows) or use a generic helper function to infer it, as shown here.

The best I can do for you is leveraging mapped types + string literal types, but the result isn't inferring the generic parameter T from propName, it requires you to pass it in manually:
type Nested<T extends string> = {
  propName: T;
  nested: {
    [P in `${T}`]: unknown
  }
}

const a: Nested<'test'> = {
  propName: 'test',
  nested: {
    test: 1, // Good
    hello: 0, // Error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'hello' does not exist in type '{ test: unknown; }'
  }
}

Trying to pass in the default parameter as string will cause the inference to break because T is then only checked to be any string, not just the literal.

P in \${T}`is the same thing asP in T, there's no difference if Tis already a subtype of string. Please [edit] to remove reference to the template literal type, since it's not doing anything.  YourNestedis essentially the same asFoo2`.

No, this is not what I’m after. I want the inference to work without having to specify the generic parameter. A use case, for example, is an Angular template. (I didn’t build that crap!)
